# An adjective that shows a "rule" is for eveyone

Tags: word-choice

Please suggest an adjective that shows a **"rule"** or **"law"** is true for everyone and there is no exception.

I thought it might be **"a public rule/law"** but I am not sure if it's a good choice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Universal", perhaps?

Comment: Thank you Hellion but it's not what I am looking for. That rule might only be true for members of a team.

Comment: I just found this: "an all-inclusive rule". I think this is good ;)

Comment: I'm not so sure. To me, that sounds like the rule covers everything (as opposed to applying to everyone). Can you elaborate on the specifics of the situation in mind?

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Thanks, but according to oxford dictionary it could also mean "including everyone".

Comment: I avoid ambiguity like I relish hot dogs.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Of course, I am trying to write few lines generally about groups of people that live together and besides the general rules that they establish, they also have a not-written "all-inclussive" rule that every member must respect it.

Comment: written and unwritten rules?

Comment: Ah yes "unwritten", it's better:) But that's not the main subject. it's a part of it. The main subject is about the conflict of freedom and justice.

Comment: In my experience, these rules are _tacit._ I'm not certain you need another word to indicate that a rule applies to everyone in a given community—that is the default behavior of rules. I think you would only need to specify if a rule did _not_ apply to all members.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Thank you. I agree with you. I think I will eventually do that :). I was just trying to put more emphasis on this aspect of rules.

Comment: This question has four close votes.  Would any close voters care to explain why?  It seems like a fine question to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use "mandatory", as in:

"It is mandatory for all bathers to wear a swimsuit."

or

"Please bring the mandatory application form with you"

Comment: Thank you, I've learned a new thing by reading your answer but it's not what I am looking for. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There could be many terms for this and it depends which context you are talking about. Also, I'll not get into the debate of whether it's [law or rule](http://www.ask.com/question/what-is-the-difference-between-a-rule-and-a-law).

Whether *rule* or *law* they both bring seriousness and are mandatory to follow/obey, but then too, to intensify them, you may simply use these options:

> Strict rule/law for everyone (i.e. there is no exception)
>  .

**Since it's about rule**, don't play with words. Be transparent and terse. I think any other option would add an ambiguity.